# php foreach username but dont foreach hay

Tags: php, foreach

I've been searching it everywhere, but i cant find the solution about this...
maybe iam using wrong keyword because i dont know what specific keyword for this problem...

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username = $user->user->username; //the echo is johnjohnbobmichaelstephenricksamuel
    $tagname= "@".$username." "; //the echo is @john @john @bob @michael @stephen @rick @samuel
}
```

When i want to make the echo of $tagname is

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username = $user->user->username; //the echo is johnjohnbobmichaelstephenricksamuel
    $tagname= "@".$username." "; //the echo is @john @john @bob @michael @stephen @rick @samuel
}
$hello = "hay ".$tagname; //the echo is hay @johnhay @johnhay @bobhay @michaelhay @stephenhay @rickhay @samuel
```

what i want is make the echo like this

```
hay @john @bob @michael @stephen @rick @samuel lets meet up
```

without looping john twice...
thank for attention everyone, forgive my language, i cant speech english to much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array of tagnames like this:

```
$tagnames = [];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username = $user->user->username; //the echo is johnjohnbobmichaelstephenricksamuel
    $tagname= "@".$username; //the echo is @john @john @bob @michael @stephen @rick @samuel
    $tagnames[] = $tagname;
}

echo "hay " . implode(' ', array_unique($tagnames));
```

Comment: it say Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: it say

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/sianiga1/public_html/a1.php on line 37

Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in /home/user/public_html/test.php on line 37
hay

Comment: Try now. Just a typo. :)

Comment: how about duplicate value likes '@john @john' ?

Comment: @mieburungdara array_unique() function removes duplicates.

Comment: @jetblack *array_unique() function removes duplicates* - I'd consider this a rather dangerous advice. The OP does not know where the duplicate john comes from and you suggest to 'ugnore' it by simply removing duplicates from the final array? The OP should check **where the duplicate user** comes from and not simply mask the symptoms.

Comment: @Paul Kertscher The question is not to find where the duplicate user comes from. It's obvious that it's comes from $users array. As we don't know the source of $users array we can't modify that. Maybe usernames are not unique in the OP's database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd doubt that the provided code is the very code you experienced issues with. Considering the following code

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username = $user->user->username; 
    $tagname= "@".$username." ";
}
$hello = "hay ".$tagname;
```

`$tagname` is reassigned with each loop iteration. Hence `$hello` should contain the last tagname, only. Hence, if we `echo $hello` the output would be *hey @samuel*. I see no reason for John being printed twice - at least not from your loop. Hence I'd suppose, that `$users` simply contains John twice. Please see the following code for a stripped down example

```
<?php

$users = ["john", "jack", "joe"];
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $tagnames = $tagnames."@".$user." ";
}
echo "hay ".$tagnames."lets go out!";
```

This snippet will output *hay @john @jack @joe  lets go out!* See [here](http://ideone.com/RjzK6L).

To investigate your issues, first of all you should consider dumping `$users` with `var_dump` - [see here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php). This should clarify your John-issue. Furthermore you should build up a better understanding of what your code does and how not to mix up the code you are using to build your output with  the code that actually outputs something.

Last but not least: Please re-check the code that actually shows the behavior you described, since I do not see that the code in your question could.